# Spring Controller gives me 404 status error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, controller

So I am attempting to write a basic Rest Controller in Spring Tool Suite with Spring annotations where I hit the endpoint "/health" and I receive the following message upon hitting the endpoint "Kafka Streaming App is healthy".

The only error I receive is the 404 status error when I check on the browser and I have already tried logging please help. I think the problem might be how I am calling the Controller in the Main Application class in Spring.

***Main Application Class***

```
    package com.eds.kafka.streaming.app;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    //import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

    //@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
    //@Configuration

    //@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.eds.kafka.streaming.model"})
    //@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.eds.kafka.streaming.service", "com.eds.kafka.streaming.util",  "com.eds.kafka.streaming.config", "com.eds.kafka.streaming.controller"}) //"com.tmobile.eds.infosec.volt.encr",
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.eds.kafka.streaming"})
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class KafkaStreamingAppContainerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(KafkaStreamingAppContainerApplication.class, args);
        }


        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
            return builder.sources(KafkaStreamingAppContainerApplication.class);
        }
    }
```

***Controller Class***

```
    package com.eds.kafka.streaming.controller;

    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
    @RestController
    public class MainController {

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/health", produces = "application/json")
        @ResponseBody 
        public ResponseEntity home() {
            System.out.println("Controller being configured!");
            return new ResponseEntity("Kafka Streaming App is Healthy", HttpStatus.OK);
        }


    }
```

Please let me know if you have any advice and if needed I can provide a zipped version of the project if that is needed just message me.

Comment: This isn't **a basic Rest Controller in Spring Tool Suite with Spring annotations** - it is a streaming/messaging platform built with Kafka. Which do you want to build? For a RESTful Web Service, start here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: First of all you do not need to use : @PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties") spring will dynamicly load the correcte properties of yaml file of the active profile whitch you app started with 
And tel us about what url do you use to acces to your rest method ?

Comment: what url you are hitting?

Comment: I am hitting "localhost:8080/health" @Alien

Comment: I have an application-dev properties file and regular application properties file beause that is the configuration I am supposed to use since I will be running this application in docker linux without using a yaml file just the property files @TinyOS

Comment: The rest of the application is Kafka functionality where it consumes data from a topic and produces data to another topic but I want to first make a basic Rest Controller that will that will display the Kafka data movement but right now I am just doing the basics with doing a sample hello message at the "/health" endpoint through the STS embedded tomcat. @RandyCasburn

Comment: You are looking at older and most likely out of date code that is guiding you astray of your goal. Let the code from the link here guide you. Please note what others are saying about your config and annotations. The sample here is a the hello world of RESTful services with a single endpoint just exactly like you want. Simply change "/greeting" to "/health" and this will be what you want. https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/tree/master/complete